# How to loop through Array<Dictionary<String,String>> using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Give me one Example and explanation for "loop through `array<Dictionary<String,String>>`using swift...

Comment: You need to be more specific... And post some of your own code, please.

Comment: Have you tried to loop through an array yet on your own?

Comment: Do you have any idea?@LyndseyScott

Comment: (1) "Looping through an array<Dictionary<String,String>>" can mean a lot of things. It's not at all specific. (2) You need to actually make some effort on your own before posting here. Writing some code on your own would be a good start.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example that shows 2 loops.  The first loops through the array picking out each dictionary.  The second loop loops through the dictionary picking out each key, value pair:

```
let people:Array<Dictionary<String,String>> = [["first":"Fred", "last":"Jones"], ["first":"Joe", "last":"Smith"]]

// Grab each person dictionary from the array of dictionaries
for person in people {
    // Grab each key, value pair from the person dictionary
    // and print it
    for (key,value) in person {
        println("\(key): \(value)")
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
first: Fred
last: Jones
first: Joe
last: Smith
```

Note that dictionaries are *unordered*, so this could also print:

```
last: Jones
first: Fred
last: Smith
first: Joe
```

Comment: You're welcome Ajay.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please tick the checkmark next to my answer to accept it.

Comment: I get the error in line "for person in people" saying "does not have a member called generator".

Comment: Did you copy the code above exactly? Which version of Xcode are you using?